# How Do I Prevent JIT Compiler From Optimising Out This Method

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, iterator, jit

I have an extension method that looks like the following:

```
//[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]
public static IEnumerable<char> TakeWhile(this BinaryReader reader, Func<int, bool> condition)
{
    while (condition(reader.PeekChar()))
    {
        char c = reader.ReadChar();
        yield return c;
    }
}
```

I use this method when parsing a file with a BinaryReader to skip a block of whitespace characters, amongst other things.  What i have found is that the JIT compiler is optimising it out, when i call it like so:

```
// Skip white space
this.reader.TakeWhile(IsWhiteSpace);//.FirstOrDefault();
```

I have tried adding the [MethodImpl(...)] attribute to instruct the JIT compiler not to optimise out the method, but it does not work.  Now obviously i could write another implementation of this which manipulates the underlying stream buffer position but out of curiosity i would like to know why this is so.

The only ways i have found to prevent the optimisation is to use the IEnumerable results (eg - via a call to .FirstOrDefault() as commented above) or copy the code into the calling method.  I have tried preventing optimisation of the calling methods, using the MethodImplAttribute, but this does not work.  Strangely, optimisation is turned off completely under the Debug build so it shouldn't be occuring in any situation.  Does anyone know another way to prevent the optimisation?

Comment: Just curious, how have you determined that it's being optimised out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the JIT *isn't* optimizing it out. However, none of your code will be executed - because you're ignoring the returned value. Until the first call to `MoveNext()`, none of the code in the iterator block is run. This has nothing to do with the JIT, and everything to do with how iterator blocks work.

You may want to read my articles on iterator blocks ([basics](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter11/StreamingAndIterators.aspx), [implementation details](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx)) and Eric Lippert's "psychic debugging" blog post ([part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/09/05/psychic-debugging-part-one.aspx); [part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/09/06/psychic-debugging-part-two.aspx)).

Note that calling `FirstOrDefault()` will only read the *first* character. It sounds like you really want to consume the whole stream until the condition fails - which means using something like `Count()` which will iterate over the entire returned sequence.

Alternatively - and preferrably IMO - write an "active" method with a void return type to do this. If you're not interested in the return value of a method, that's a signal that it's probably not an ideal method to call. (That's not *always* the case, but it usually is.)

Comment: In addition to this reply, I feel I should mention that an iterator isn't what you want here in the first place. You're not *iterating* over the white space, you're ignoring it, ie this is a *function call* in the imperative sense.

Comment: @Blindy: I was just adding something similar :)

Comment: ugggh - my god you are right, silly me - the caller needs to PULL the values from the iterator, as its not going to push them out.  Thanks.  Nice article by Lippert there :)

Comment: One more addition: In your comment, you say "Skip", so why don't you name and implement your method like a Skip method?

Comment: @Daniel: The method itself is actually much more like the LINQ "Take" method. It's only when you ignore the returned sequence but reuse the same BinaryReader that it can be viewed as skipping :)

Comment: I know :-) But in LINQ, you also have a Skip and a Take method. One for each task. That was what I was asking: Why isn't he doing it the same way?

Comment: @Daniel: But LINQ's Skip works completely differently. The method *is* named appropriately, it's just being used *inappropriately*. A similar method which *imperatively* ignored the data would be appropriately named Skip.

Comment: @Jon: I think, you are misunderstanding me. I know, that Skip and Take are working differently. And because that is the case, I was wondering, why the OP uses a Take method to fulfill the job of a Skip method. His method is named and behaves like a Take method. He is using it as a Skip method, hence my question, why he is using the wrong tool for the job, so to speak.

Comment: @Daniel: Right, yes, it's the wrong tool for the job - hence the last paragraph of my answer :)